# Break within while loop not working (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I have the code below:

```
def inputfcn():
    while True:
        x = raw_input("y/n: ")
        if x == "y":
            break
    return
```

It makes me input `y` twice before breaking. Did I miss something?

Comment: It works when I execute it in python shell, so maybe the problem is not in  this code but in the code that is executing this function?

Comment: *Did i miss something*: you apparently did not enter (just) `y` the first time. Your code works, there is nothing here that'd make it fail the first time round unless you didn't actually enter `y` *exactly*.

Comment: Did you call `inputfcn()` multiple times?

Comment: Hm, looks fine, maybe consider `if x.strip().lower() == "y":`

Comment: Hint, for debug purposes you may actually print value of x before doing comparison. `print x` and `print repr(x)` will tell you what exactly is compared to what.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Without seeing any more, I'd guess you are probably calling this function twice. Search for the function name. Is it called by two if statements that could both be true? If so, then you have to hit "y" twice because the function runs twice.

To test, print something right before you break the while loop. You should see that this function is running twice.

Comment: sorry, yes. I have just called it twice. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right, You just need to check from where you call the function, I think at that point function calls twice. if it will not help you please give us full code so that we can debug it.

Comment: it is working now turns out i am calling the function for another run in one of the other sub functions. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Your code just looks fine. I think you entered capital 'Y' first time.